# RackSpace Relative path to css/stylesheet images

Tags: css, image, cdn, rackspace-cloud

I m going to use Rack space cloud as CDN for Delivering Images and CSS/Stylesheets.

The CSS files contains images as a relative path to the image location.

My image folder contains sub folders like

1./images/home/banner.jpg
2./images/home/fb/like.png

I dont want to change the relative path of the images in css files.

How can i upload my images to CDN (Rack Space Cloud) So that i don't need to change anything in the css files?

Help me folks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make the image paths relative to the css file or put your images folder where the CSS file is.